# When 亏 is kuī ? when yú?

Tags: pronunciation

The dictionary entry for 亏 is:

亏 kuī(or yú) lose, fail, damage, deficient

When will 亏 be pronounced as yú?

Comment: I never used 亏 as yú in my entire life, even didn't know it pronounces yú as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All of your definitions (e.g., `吃虧`, `虧損`, `虧蝕`) appertain to the pronunciation `kuī` – for this reason, memorising `kuī` suffices. The pronunciation `yú` is far less important.
2. As for the pronunciation `yú`, it is likely to be a glyphic variant of `于` (a character you have asked [before](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/43485/27428)) (see below, from [Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%8F)). From the viewpoint of glyph evolution, the character pronounced `kuī` was first written as `虧` in traditional script no later than Han dynasty, only simplified into `亏` in the 20th century. The rationale of simplification being, `亏` is a relatively obscure yet graphically related character. Now it has become the dominant meaning associated to `亏`.

[image: baidu]

References:

- [Baidu Baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%8F)
- [Multi-function Chinese Character Database](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%8F)

Answer (score 1):

*Grand Ricci* says:

> 亏
> yú
> V. n. 11938 于 yú.

It looks like it is a rare variant of 于/於. It doesn't seem to be anything that you'd really come across these days in the wild though.